# Value of the integral $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx?$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am confused about the value of the integral $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx,$ is it $0$ or not always? In Riemann integration case (i.e. $f$ is bounded ) its zero by definition. What about other cases for example $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}? $ Is it zero? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is ${1\over x}$ defined at $x=0$?

Comment: its not defined in case of improper integral...

Comment: It is always zero, assuming that the measure of $\{a\}$ is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat   i don't have knowledge of measure theory....is it means that  on the set of measure zero any function has zero integration? is it right?

Comment: I don't know how to answer if you don't have any measure theory. The integral can be defined as $\int f \cdot 1_{\{a\}} $ and since $ f \cdot 1_{\{a\}} = 0$ ae., then $\int  f \cdot 1_{\{a\}} = \int 0 = 0$.

Comment: "its not defined in case of improper integral": no, $1/0$ is never defined.

Comment: Hi. I asked the same question before. It is here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728993/what-is-displaystyle-int-22-fracdxx-2

Comment: @studentforever Interesting how the answers there disagree with the ones here.

Comment: I actually care this definition now. (Definition 1.34) https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780735/72031

Answer (score 4):

It's always zero...except that there are some conventions in which this notation is used to denote something that's not zero.

So let me clarify "always": for the Riemann integral, and for the  Lesbegue integral with respect to the standard measure on the real line, and for functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, it's always zero. This property is very useful, for it helps ensure that 
$$
\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c
$$
in general.

So why do I say "except..."?

Well, for instance, if $f$ is a "delta function" (which isn't really a function, but instead a distribution), then this integral can denote something nonzero (or at least
$$
\int_{0^{-}}^{0^{+}} f(x) dx
$$
can be nonzero).

And if your measure "dx" on the real line happens to assign positive measure to the point $0$, then again the integral can denote something nonzero. But it'd be pretty odd to use "dx" to denote such a measure.

Comment: Just inquiring, is your "delta" function something similar to Dirac-Delta function?

Comment: Yes...except that the so-called "Dirac delta function" isn't a function, so I tend not to call it one. :)

Comment: Okay. I dont know much about it, just what it means, so I thought it was analogous. Anyways, I won't (from today) call it a function( Thanks for that)

Answer (score 2):

The heart of your question comes down to what we mean by the word *integral*. The most reasonable value for $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is probably $0$, and for this reason nobody would object to you giving the value of this integral as $0$. I expound on this below.

Let $a<b$ be real numbers and let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Broadly speaking, if $\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is defined for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, then we usually would define $\int_{c}^{c}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ to be zero. This is simply because defining it any other way would be strange: our intuitive picture of what the integral means is "an area under a graph". It then makes intuitive sense that, if the area under the graph is a meaningful concept for some small interval around $c$ (that is, if the function is integrable on $[c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon]$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $\epsilon>0$), then the area under the graph (the value of the integral) should get smaller and smaller (tend to zero) as we make the interval smaller (as $\epsilon\to0$).

Ultimately, a fair amount of what is true in pure mathematics comes down to what we *define* to be true. We make the definitions ourselves according to what we consider to be "reasonable". Whether or not the statement above is actually true for any particular definition of "integral" depends on the definitions, either of the integral itself or just of integrals with these kinds of limits. My point is that most "reasonable" definitions of "integral" are called "reasonable" at least in part because this statement *is* true for them. If it weren't, they wouldn't (usually) be very good definitions of "integral".

This solves the problem in cases where the function is sufficiently integrable. In other cases, such as the example $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ that you give, whether or not the value is $0$ is again dependent on what we *define* it to be. If we wanted to, we could define $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi$ and see where that gets us, but we would never want to do this because this makes little sense. The most reasonable value would be $0$, for a couple of reasons.

1. The integrand is an odd function, and we expect from our knowledge of "nice" situations that the integral of an odd function on an interval symmetric about $0$ should evaluate to $0$. Since $\{0\}$ is in a perverse sense "an interval symmetric about $0$", it makes sense to define the value of the integral based on this other result.
2. A related way to come up with a reasonable definition is to take inspiration from other reasonable definitions, in this case the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). The Cauchy principal value allows us to assign values to certain improper integrals by imagining the area under the graph as "expanding out from the origin". In this case, we may instead imagine the area as expanding *in* from outside the origin. With this picture in mind, we might define
   $$\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-}}\left(\int_{-1}^{-1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=0\right).$$
   Now the calculation is easy: for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ we have $\int_{-1}^{-1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=0$ by symmetry (either evaluate the integral or draw a diagram). Hence the limit is $0$.

The important thing to take away here is that if something is *undefined*, you may sometimes feel free to define it yourself; the important thing is that the definition should be mathematically *reasonable*. Of course, what is reasonable and what isn't reasonable is another question entirely! Figuring out the right answer to this question is often the main goal of much mathematical research.

Answer (score -2):

You can say like this $$\int_0^0{1\over x}dx=\lim_{c\to0+}\int_{-c}^{c}{1\over x}dx=\lim_{c\to0+}\left[\ln|x|\right]_{-c}^c=\lim_{c\to 0+}\{\ln|c|-\ln|-c|\}=0$$

Comment: i just put one example....but may question is that in general is it true?

Comment: @neelkanth Yes it is. For such similar questions, approach by taking limits, like I did. Please accept my answer if you liked it.

Comment: You can say that, @Qwerty, but it doesn't make it right. :)  For the first equality assumes that the integral on the interval $[-c, c]$ exists for each small $c$, while $f$ might not even be defined on that interval, or might be non-integrable there.

Comment: @JohnHughes I accept your logic, (though I have not come over such functions till now). But I think , my answer was just enough to clear the OP's doubt. Anyways +1 for you "exceptional case."

Comment: @Qwerty: I don't understand what $\int_{-c}^{c}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is supposed to mean; the integrand is not defined on the region of integration, so how are you defining the integral? Also your second equality seems to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in some form, but that theorem is not applicable here since the antiderivative $\ln{\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert}$ is not defined everywhere on the interval $[-c,c]$. Could you try to provide more details?

Comment: @WillR In general, when you are given a function to integrate over an interval(continuous), such that it is not defined at 1 particular point in that interval, do you consider the value it takes over just that particular point? No, because the value the function takes over 1 particular point **doesnot change** the area it covers in that interval.

Comment: @Qwerty: Okay, that's fair enough I suppose. You're suggesting we just set $f(0)=\text{whatever}$ and $f(x)=1/x$ elsewhere. But then there's another problem: the function is unbounded on the interval. This alone is not always too bad since we might define the integral of some unbounded functions to be $\pm\infty$, but in this case it seems like a naive perspective would give something like $\infty+(-\infty)$, which is again undefined. I also don't understand how/why the antiderivative $\ln$ comes into play.

Comment: I suppose one definition which would give the same answer (which, by the way, I concede is fairly intuitive; after all, the integrand is an odd function) would be to define $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-}}\int_{-1+\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$ The idea is that we calculate values of the area by moving *inwards* towards zero, rather than outwards from zero. For every value of $\epsilon>0$ the calculation here clearly gives $0$ by symmetry, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: @WillR Well your last technique (moving inwards) looks promising. You might well get upvotes if you write it out as an answer

Comment: That approach is one way to define a value for such an integral, but another is $\lim_{a \to a, b \to 0} \int_a^b f(x) ~ dx$; in this case, the answer ends  up undefined because the limit doesn't exist. Why should the symmetric form be preferred? Making good and consistent definitions for stuff like this can be pretty tricky!

Comment: @WillR That integral in the limit doesn't make any sense. You're integrating over the singularity at $0$. It doesn't matter if it's symmetric; the function is unbounded there and hence not Riemann integrable. I don't think there's any salvaging this either, since the integrals from either side don't independently converge.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I meant to define $$\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-1}}\left(\int_{-1}^{-1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right).$$ I did not suggest anything like $$\lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-1}}\left(\int_{-1}^{-1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right) = \lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-1}}\int_{-1}^{-1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \lim_{\epsilon\to1^{-1}}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ was true. See my full answer.

Comment: To the downvoters: Maybe my answer wasn't as **perfect** as yours , but I think it was enough to clear the OP's doubt. So why $-3$ votes?

Comment: For the record I didn't vote on this question, and it occurs to me now that if we were to remove your first equality and just write $\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{c\to0^{+}}[\ln{\lvert x \rvert}]_{c}^{c}=\cdots=0,$ then your fix would amount to the same as mine (with a slight change of variable). So I don't think this answer should be so harshly treated.

Comment: @WillR So will you be kind enough to give an upvote to somewhat minimise this (I think) unfair treatment?

Comment: Not only is this not perfect, it's just plainly wrong. The downvotes are deserved imo as having such an answer upvoted gives the impression that this is allowed math while (as explained in other answers and in the comments above) the true story is that the integral simply does not exist in any traditional sense so your calculations are simply meaningless.